# kube-proxy does not run, however shows in output of "kubectl get pod" as normally running

Tags: kubernetes

The kube-proxy runs as a daemonset, so I see that there are two pods in my 2 nodes cluster:

```
kube-proxy-4f246                           1/1     Running   0          14d
kube-proxy-7hzkf                           1/1     Running   2          5m43s
```

After doing kubectl describe pod kube-proxy-7hzkf -n kube-system I get the ID of the container.

```
kube-proxy:
Container ID:  docker://53f81d08adaa9b29b7ac8d985c40d08500e84e1be96732ae7a91744a735df885
```

Then I am checking at the node that this kube-proxy is running that kube-proxy is running as a process, also there is a containerd process related to that kube-proxy instance:

```
ubuntu@k8s-2:~$ ps aux|grep 53f81d08adaa9b29b7ac8d985c40d08500e84e1be
root     31328  0.0  0.2 113964  8276 ?        Sl   12:21   0:00 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id 53f81d08adaa9b29b7ac8d985c40d08500e84e1be96732ae7a91744a735df885 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Also:

```
ubuntu@k8s-2:~$ ps aux|grep kube-proxy
root     31355  0.0  1.0 747380 40520 ?        Ssl  12:21   0:00 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=k8s-2
```

If the kube-proxy process dies, this is what happens below, the Kubernetes is restarting the failed kube-proxy.

```
kube-system   0s          Normal    Pulled                    pod/kube-proxy-7hzkf                   Container image "k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.21.1" already present on machine
kube-system   0s          Normal    Created                   pod/kube-proxy-7hzkf                   Created container kube-proxy
kube-system   0s          Normal    Started                   pod/kube-proxy-7hzkf                   Started container kube-proxy
default       0s          Normal    Starting                  node/k8s-2                             Starting kube-proxy.
```

However if the containerd-shim-runc-v2 process dies, the kube-proxy as well goes down , but then nothing is restarted and the node stays without kube-proxy, although everything seems OK in Kubernetes , no event shows up and the output of kubectl get pod etc. , kubectl describe shows the kube-proxy running!

What happens here??

```
ubuntu@k8s-1:~$ kubectl get pod -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
..
..
kube-proxy-4f246                           1/1     Running   0          14d
kube-proxy-7hzkf                           1/1     Running   3          15m
kube-scheduler-k8s-1                       1/1     Running   0          47h
..

ubuntu@k8s-2:~$ ps aux|grep kube-proxy
ubuntu   10879  0.0  0.0  14864  1048 pts/0    S+   12:36   0:00 grep --color=auto kube-proxy
ubuntu@k8s-2:~$
```

So the last one shows no kube-proxy running!

Comment: Hello @maiky Do you know if kube-proxy on k8s-2 worked fine previously? Have you made any changes to your infrastructure/kubernetes last time? Which version of kubernetes are you using?

Comment: Hello @maiky. Any updates?